# How to display dynamic tooltip?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In a customized wxScrolledWindow, there are many nodes and edges which are displayed.
When mouse rolls over some kinds of the nodes, I can calculate which node is covered by the mouse and want to show a tooltip about the information of the nodes.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets has a wxTipWindow class that you can use for this. Define an EVT_ENTER_WINDOW mouse event handler. The handler will get called when the mouse cursor is inside one of your nodes. Inside of the handling function you can create a new wxTipWindow to show extra info for your nodes.

Comment: It does not work. I use mouse move event handler, and it can display different tooltips for every node, but it will not show tip for another node until a left button mouse clicking event triggers to close the wxTipWindow.